# Submitting model with entities in MVC using DataTable fails when using pagination

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I want to submit model with entities, but controller is not receiving entities when switching to another page when using DataTable plugin.

VIEW:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditLeads", new { mode = Model.leadMode }, new AjaxOptions {     OnBegin = "displayAllDataTable", UpdateTargetId = "leadDisplay", LoadingElementId =     "spinner", OnSuccess = "refreshLeadsAfterRemovingAndTabSwitching" }, new  {     id="dataTableForm"}))
{ 
<table id="dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="max-width: 40px;">
                Select
            </th>

            <th>
                Date added
            </th>
            <th>
                Contact name
            </th>
            <th>
                Contact number
            </th>
            <th>
                Email
            </th>
            <th>
                Source
            </th>
            <th>
                Status
            </th>
            <th>
                Assigned to user:
            </th>
            <th>
                Back up user:
            </th>
            <th>
                Comments
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.leadsList.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">
                <span class="hideDisplayField">@Model.leadsList[i].leadId</span>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.organisationId)
                 @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.leadsList[i].leadId)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.leadsList[i].selected, new { @class = "selectedLead", data_val = false, data_leadId = Model.leadsList[i].leadId, id = "selected_" + Model.leadsList[i].leadId })
                </td>
               @* <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.leadsList[i].leadId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.leadsList[i].leadId)
                </td>*@
                <td>
                    <span class="hideDisplayField">@Model.leadsList[i].leadDate</span>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.leadsList[i].leadDate)
                </td>
                @*  <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.leadsList[i].leadId)
                    <span class="hideDisplayField">@Model.leadsList[i].description</span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.leadsList[i].description)
                </td>*@
                <td>
                    <span class="hideDisplayField">@Model.leadsList[i].contactName</span>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.leadsList[i].contactName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="hideDisplayField">@Model.leadsList[i].contactMobile</span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.leadsList[i].contactMobile)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="hideDisplayField">@Model.leadsList[i].contactEmail</span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.leadsList[i].contactEmail)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.leadsList[i].contactId)
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="hideDisplayField">@Model.leadsList[i].leadStatusName</span>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.leadsList[i].leadStatusId, new SelectList(Model.leadStatusList, "leadStatusId", "name", Model.leadsList[i].leadStatusId), null, new { data_val = false })
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="hideDisplayField">@Model.leadsList[i].assignedToUserId</span>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.leadsList[i].assignedToUserId, new SelectList(Model.users, "UserId", "Email", Model.leadsList[i].assignedToUserId), "Select user", new { data_val = false, data_users = Model.leadsList[i].leadId, @class = "usersList" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="hideDisplayField">@Model.leadsList[i].backupUserId</span>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.leadsList[i].backupUserId, new SelectList(Model.users, "UserId", "Email", Model.leadsList[i].backupUserId), "Select user", new { data_val = false })
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Select
            </th>

            <th>
                Date added
            </th>
            <th>
                Contact name
            </th>
            <th>
                Contact mobile
            </th>
            <th>
                Email
            </th>
            <th>
                Source
            </th>
            <th>
                Status
            </th>
            <th>
                Assigned to user
            </th>
            <th>
                Back up user
            </th>
            <th>
                Comments
            </th>

        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<div id="assignUserToLeads">
    <h4>
        Assign selected to</h4>
    @Html.DropDownList("userList", new SelectList(Model.users, "UserId", "Email"), "Select user")
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

My constroller is expecting to receive model with list of leads.

```
public ActionResult EditLeads(LeadsVM leadVM, string mode, FormCollection form)
    {
        // Assign user to lead

        var user = form["userList"];

        var leadsToUpdate = leadVM.leadsList.Where(m => m.selected == true);

        foreach (var lead in leadsToUpdate) ...
```

If I select value from dropdown list to display 100 items on page, everything works fine, but once I switch to another page, name binding is falling apart and model is passing null for leadVM.leadsList. I did small hack which I thought might help. Before model is send to controller I am calling displayAllDataTable function.

```
function displayAllDataTable() {
        console.log($("#dataTable_length select"));
        $("#dataTable_length select").val(100);
        $("#dataTable_length select").trigger("change");
    }
```

Unfortunately the function forces dataTable to display all results on 1st page, but model still passes null for leadsList. I would assume I will have to call some dataTable function to refresh the fields in table and then the form can be correctly submitted, but there must be simpler way.

To summarize I always want to pass all data from table to controller, regardless on which page I am currently in.

DataTable

```
table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
                'dom': '<lf<"table_wrapper"t>ip>',
                "aoColumns": [
                { "bSearchable": true },
                { "bSearchable": true },
                { "bSearchable": true },
                { "bSearchable": true },
                { "bSearchable": true },
                { "bSearchable": true },
                { "bSearchable": false },
                { "bSearchable": false },
                { "bSearchable": false },
                { "bSearchable": true }
                ]

            });
```

Comment: How are you initializing your datatable?

Answer (score 2):

Found solution!

First I tweaked a value in dataTables js.

```
  "aLengthMenu": [ 10, 25, 50, 100, 1000 ].
```

I added 1000, but you can add any value you want.

Under form I changed input type from submit to button and called function.

```
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="displayAllDataTable()">
```

I define the function:

```
function displayAllDataTable() {

        $("#dataTable_length select").val(1000);
        $("#dataTable_length select").trigger("change");

        $("#dataTableForm").submit();

    }
```

Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I read through API documentation and came up with another solution that allows databinding by drawing the entire table with page.len.  This would not be an ideal solution with a large table with thousands of rows, and would look weird from a UI perspective as the entire table draws before form submits to controller.  Also I noted that on the Controller side, that if you are binding to a list from the Datatable, the ordering of the binding / list is not in respect to the Datatable ordering.

[page.len](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.len())

Here is source to add to the end of your page:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.legacy.ajax = true;
        $('#YourTable').dataTable();
    });

    $("#YourTable").submit(function (event) {
        var table = $('#YourTable').DataTable();
        table.page.len(-1).draw();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Adam Bielecki post, I've tweked it a little bit to avoid a 1,000 lenght option as follows... just use -1 instead!

```
 lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, **-1**], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]




function displayAllDataTable() {
            $("#example1_length select").val(**-1**);
            $("#example1_length select").trigger("change");

            $("#groupForm").submit();
}
```